# Python: Lock directory access under windows

Tags: python, windows, directory, locking

I'd like to be able to lock directory access under windows.
The following code work greatly with file or directory under POSIX system:

```
def flock(fd, blocking=False, exclusive=False):

    if exclusive:
        flags = fcntl.LOCK_EX
    else:
        flags = fcntl.LOCK_SH
    if not blocking:
        flags |= fcntl.LOCK_NB
    fcntl.flock(fd, flags)
```

But I only find a way to perform lock access for file, not directory with the following code:

```
def flock(fd, blocking=False, exclusive=False):

    if blocking:
        flags = msvcrt.LK_NBLCK
    else:
        flags = msvcrt.LK_LOCK
    msvcrt.locking(fd.fileno(), flags, os.path.getsize(fd.name))
```

Have you got any idea how to improve this code and be able to lock directory access ?

Bertrand

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to use flock() on directories in windows.  [PHPs docs](https://www.php.net/flock) on flock() indicate that it won't even work on FAT32 filesystems.

On the other hand, Windows already tends to not allow you to delete files/directories if any files are still open.  This, plus maybe using ACLs intelligently, might get you a 95% equivalent solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do something like this to indirectly lock a directory with the latter flock function.

```
for file in os.listdir(dir):
 f = open(file)
 flock(f)
```

This is a limited version, since the user will be able to create new files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you are right, at least I can try to lock every file of the directory but it can be painful because I need to walk into all the subdirectories of my directory.
In POSIX system it's easy because directories are seen like files so, no problem with that. But in Windows when I try to open a directory, it doesn't really like that.

```
open(dirname)
```

raises exception:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: dirname
```

I am not really sure my solution is actually the good way to do it.